# How to show full content in wordpress when advertise in page hide some content?

Tags: php, wordpress

My site is http://career.guru99.com/

I am using Wordpress 3.6

some content like bullets in document is hide because of advertise in Wordpress.

You can check here what i am talking about - http://screencast.com/t/W9Px6SUqpT

so how can i overcome this issue. i am facing this problem from 4 months but still not getting any solution.

Please suggest your ideas and solution so i can solve this issue.

Please help

Comment: I would suggest jQuery or similar but what have you tried?

Comment: I have no any idea about this issue. Then how can i trie anything.

Comment: In which case hire a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Positioning section](http://alistapart.com/article/taminglists/#section2) of the "Taming Lists" article at A List Apart. It mentions that sometimes item markers are outside of DIV, and what to do to bring them back in.